# Product Detail page custom option in accordion not validating in Magneto 2.4.6

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, custom-options

After upgrading Magento 2.3.3 to 2.4.6-p3, custom options of product are not being validated in Magneto 2.4.6. In Magneto 2.3.3 we added validation ignore to apply validation on hidden field

```
$('.catalog-product-view #product_addtocart_form').mage('validation', {
    ignore: []
});
```

This was working fine in Magento 2.3.3 but not after upgrading. Any suggestion on this, please. There is something wrong with latest version of jQuery and mage validation js.

Answer (score 0):

**Please update code for validation**

```
 $("#product_addtocart_form").validation('isValid');
```

Now we have the validation() method to check the validation of the form.